# get output of Html.BeginForm() into string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get the string output of Html.BeginForm() as a string inside a view, without printing it in the view. Is it possible?

EDIT >

I am trying to implement some text helpers to work with html tags inside C#, such ass:

```
using(Html.BeginText("p")){
    Hi, my name is Ashley. I love 

    using(Html.BeginText("small")){
        small letters
    }
}
```

I used IDisposable, so I don't have to worry about the closing tags and I can insert html text inside the brackets, but I want to get this values as string, not to print it to the user.

Comment: Why do you need it ?

Comment: I will edit with more information. give me a second

Comment: Agreed, this has a bad code smell to it. It seems like maybe the wrong way to go about what you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: why you don't use a static function?

Comment: I would have to call the closing tag as well, being more error prone for the user